# how to create a datatable that allows sorting, pagination and search

Tags: jquery, html, flask, datatable

I've been trying to make a datatable work similar to an example on datatable.net but I'm not too sure how I should funnel the data into the table in a way to allow the data table to work as in the example here: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Right now I copied their HTML and plan to edit it from there to make the table work. I plan to use the pagination, search and sort functions in the future as well, so I'll have to get everything in the example to work as it does in the site.

Is there a quick way to get everything to run appropriately? I'm running a flask app.

-e-

To clarify, I hope to get the pagination, search and sort to work as a start, similar to something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45933110/edit

Current table:

HTML code:

```
{% extends "pages.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div id="example_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="dataTables_length" id="example_length"><label>Show <select name="example_length"
                                                                                   aria-controls="example"
                                                                                   class="form-control input-sm">
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>entries</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div id="example_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input type="search"
                                                                                    class="form-control input-sm"
                                                                                    placeholder=""
                                                                                    aria-controls="example"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" cellspacing="0"
                   width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%;">
                <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                        aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending"
                        style="width: 135px;">Name
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                        aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 219px;">
                        Position
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                        aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 100px;">Office
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                        aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 44px;">Age
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                        aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 92px;">
                        Start date
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
                        aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 76px;">Salary
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Name</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Position</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Office</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Age</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Start date</th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Salary</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="dataTables_info" id="example_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 10
                of 57 entries
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example_paginate">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="example_previous"><a
                            href="#"
                            aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a></li>
                    <li class="paginate_button active"><a
                            href="#"
                            aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
                    <li class="paginate_button "><a
                            href="#"
                            aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a></li>
                    <li class="paginate_button "><a
                            href="#"
                            aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a></li>
                    <li class="paginate_button "><a
                            href="#"
                            aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a></li>
                    <li class="paginate_button "><a
                            href="#"
                            aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a></li>
                    <li class="paginate_button "><a
                            href="#"
                            aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">6</a></li>
                    <li class="paginate_button next" id="example_next"><a
                            href="#"
                            aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0">Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

pages.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% block head %}

    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>



    {% block scripts %}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    {% endblock %}

    <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/agency.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Datatable JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out jquery needs to be put in the HTML file that I'm trying to run the table in, and {% extends '' %} doesn't extend the script call it seems.